# SetCursorPos moving mouse twice?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm making a program that allows users to customize hotkeys and make them perform specific functions.

The first function that I have made moves the cursor to a specific set of coordinates within the game window. It does this by finding the client area then adding the set coordinates and then moving the cursor there. However, it appears that each time SetCursorPos is called, it moves twice: first to the correct spot, the to (0,0). I'm not sure what's causing this, and I've spent hours googling and debugging to no avail. Everything works correctly except that it moves twice. I'm using Windows 8 and compiling with Code::Blocks.

The script outputs what coordinates it should be moving too before the mouse moves and after. They should be the same. It also outputs "key down" when the hotkey is pressed down and "key up" when it is released.

Pressing F1 will cause the mouse to move.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

class macro{
public:
    int x, y, w, h;
    HWND hWnd;

    HWND get_hWnd(){
        hWnd   =   FindWindow(NULL,"Untitled - Notepad");
        return hWnd;
    }

    void get_Pos(){
        RECT pos;
        GetClientRect(hWnd,(LPRECT)&pos);
        ClientToScreen(hWnd,(LPPOINT)&pos.left);
        ClientToScreen(hWnd,(LPPOINT)&pos.right);
        w   =   pos.right;
        h   =   pos.bottom;
        x   =   pos.left;
        y   =   pos.top;
    }
    void activate(){
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
    }
    void initialize(){
        get_hWnd();
        get_Pos();
    }
    void mousemove(int rx, int ry){
        get_Pos();
        cout << "Pre-move: " << rx+x << "," << ry+y << endl;
        SetCursorPos(rx + x,ry + y);
        cout << "Post-move: " << rx+x << "," << ry+y << endl;
    }
}macro;

int main(){
    macro.initialize();
    bool loop   =   true;
    bool action_complete    =   true;
    int prev    =   0;
    int curr    =   0;
    bool key_state; // True if down, false if up.

    while(loop){
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(0x70)){
            curr    =   1;
        }
        else{
            curr    =   0;
        }
        if (prev != curr){
            if(curr){
                key_state   =   true;
                macro.mousemove(100,100);
                cout << "key down" << endl;
                Sleep(100);
            }
            else{
                key_state   =   false;
                cout << "key up" << endl;
                Sleep(100);
            }
            prev    =   curr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like it will move the mouse cursor only once. You probably have some system wide settings on the mouse like "Automatically move pointer to the default button in a dialog" set and this could be causing the other move.

Comment: Here are my mouse settings: http://i.imgur.com/bj4dV2V.png, so that option isn't set.

Comment: Does this happen with the game closed?

Comment: If you press F1 before loading the game, it won't work. However, if you load the game, or if the game is loaded when the program is run, it will happen, even if you close it.

Comment: Turns out that it works with every key except F1.